# Idiomatic way of filtering data in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some collection of data which I show using `ng-repeat` directive:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.products = [...]; // data from server
});

<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also I have some filter buttons: `"Newest"`, `"Popular"` etc.

And I want to filter my data when clicking on this buttons.

Currently I think I can just define separate event-handler for each of this button in controller, and programmatically filter the `products` variable:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.products = [...]; // data from server

    $scope.showNewest = function() {
        // here modify the  $scope.products  varialbe so changes will be reflected in UI
    }
});
```

But I think it's ugly solution. And I feel that better way is to define custom filter, but now I haven't any ideas how new filter should look. So what is idiomatic/better way to accomplish my task?

Comment: [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) doesn't do it for you?

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, make a custom filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @RobertHarvey @Patrick Reck  yes, but the problem is that I don't know how to notify filter inside `ng-repeat="product in products | myFilter"` which button was clicked.

Comment: You don't need to notify it, just pass data to it like `ng-repeat="product in products | myFilter:filterCriteria"` and it should work automatically even without passing data due to two-way binding. Notice, that you need to modufy data in a way that angular would know the data has been modified

Comment: @IlyaIvanov where from `filterCriteria` will come?

Comment: @WelcomeTo from the scope

Comment: @IlyaIvanov can you please expand you things? As I understand I  should create custom filter `myFilter` with 1 argument `filterCriteria`, also create separete event-handlers for each button, and inside those event-handlers I need to modify the `filterCriteria` scope varialbe? If so, then I think it's not good idea, because my custom filter will actually encapsulate behaviors of several different filters